# How to strictly check if a collection exists upon attribute-style access in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Accessing a collection as `db.mycollection.find()` can *silently fail* if there is a typo in the collection name, e.g. `db.mycollections.find()`.

Can pymongo be configured to raise an exception if the collection doesn't exist?

Errors are good!

Comment: I agree that an error would be preferable, but if you get stonewalled there's always `if collectionname in db.collection_names()`.

Comment: you can submit a feature request for this as well as track it at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON

Comment: Done - at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-376